# How to check if background color is set on Image view?

Tags: android

I want to set background color on Image view if it doesn't already have background color.

I'm trying something like this, but obviously it won't work. How can I set

```
private ImageView myImage = findViewById(R.id.myimage);

if (myImage.getBackground() != null) {
    myImage..setBackgroundColor(0x00000000)
}
else {
    myImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
}
```

This work to set background color and remove it, but only the first time. The problem is that when background is set to `0x00000000` it's transparent, hence not null. Is it possible to set background color to null? Or do I need to set the background as transparent by default and check if it's transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `setBackgroundColor` to transparent. `setBackgroundColor` will create a `ColorDrawable` for the background. Since `setBackgroundColor` requires you to provide it an `ColorInt` you cannot invoke it with `null`. What you can do though is to replace `setBackgroundColor(0x00000000)` with `setBackground(null)`